# Calculating difference between first and individual occurence (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

Let's take a look at a simple HR dataframe as an example:

| Name | Year | Department | Salary | New column: *hit100after* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2018 | R&D | 80 | *0* |
| Marie | 2018 | Legal | 90 | *0* |
| Jill | 2018 | Legal | 100 | *0* |
| John | 2019 | R&D | 85 | *0* |
| Marie | 2019 | Legal | 95 | *0* |
| Jill | 2019 | Legal | 105 | *1* |
| John | 2020 | R&D | 90 | *0* |
| Marie | 2020 | Legal | 100 | *2* |
| Jill | 2020 | Legal | 110 | *2* |

**Question**: How much time (in years) did it take for any data set to achieve a salary >= 100 AFTER the first person in the same department hit that number? (see new column 'hit100after')

I am actually struggeling with the implementation. My steps would be to group by department and find the first occurrence of salary >= 100 and mark that year with a new boolean type or a second dataframe. Then I would calculate the differences between >= 100 of an individual and the first occurrence in its department.

Any idea how to code that for a large dataframe?

Comment: the number of hit100after in Jill 2018 should be 1?

Comment: 100 occurs the first time in 2018 in legal. So the value of hit100after can only be 0 because 0 years have passed since this 'occurence event'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**`groupby()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `Department` and find the `Year.min()` where `Salary >= 100`:

```py
first100 = df.groupby('Department').apply(
    lambda g: g[g.Salary >= 100].Year.min())

# Department
# Legal    2018.0
# R&D         NaN
# dtype: float64
```

Then [**`map()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) those `first100` years by `Department` and subtract from `Year`. The results are in `Result` for comparison:

```py
df['Result'] = df.Year - df.Department.map(first100)
df.loc[df.Salary < 100, 'Result'] = 0

#     Name  Year Department  Salary  Hit100after  Result
# 0   John  2018        R&D      80            0     0.0
# 1  Marie  2018      Legal      90            0     0.0
# 2   Jill  2018      Legal     100            0     0.0
# 3   John  2019        R&D      85            0     0.0
# 4  Marie  2019      Legal      95            0     0.0
# 5   Jill  2019      Legal     105            1     1.0
# 6   John  2020        R&D      90            0     0.0
# 7  Marie  2020      Legal     100            2     2.0
# 8   Jill  2020      Legal     110            2     2.0
```

---

#### Timings for the current answers

| method | `%timeit` with 1 million rows |
| --- | --- |
| this answer | 3.07 ms ± 23.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each) |
| `query()` answer | 4.33 ms ± 354 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each) |

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```py
new_col = (df.query("Salary >= 100")
             .groupby("Department")
             .apply(lambda x: x.Year - x.iloc[0].Year)
             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
             .T)
df["hit100after"] = new_col
df["hit100after"] = df["hit100after"].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

First we look at those entries with salary greater than 100 (`query`), then group them by the department (`groupby`), apply a function to get the year differences with respect to the first entry in the department (`apply` and `iloc[0]`), get rid of the department names (`reset_index` on 0th level with `drop` being `True`) and take a transpose (`T`) to ensure it is vertical to ease the alignment with the original `df`.

Lastly we assign this new column to the `df` but then since we only selected those with `Salary >= 100`, there are `NaN`s when assigned; hence the `fillna(0)`. Since `NaN` is technically a floating number it made the series floating, so we cast to `int` at the end.

To get:

```
    Name  Year Department  Salary  hit100after
0   John  2018        R&D      80            0
1  Marie  2018      Legal      90            0
2   Jill  2018      Legal     100            0
3   John  2019        R&D      85            0
4  Marie  2019      Legal      95            0
5   Jill  2019      Legal     105            1
6   John  2020        R&D      90            0
7  Marie  2020      Legal     100            2
8   Jill  2020      Legal     110            2
```

Comment: +1 I don't see `query` much, so nice to see it in use. I timed it out of curiosity and it seems just *slightly* slower than my version though.

Comment: @tdy Yours is much more concise, readable and robust (e.g. mine fails when index has duplicates) and much faster (I tried with a dataframe where more than one department has >= 100; twice as slow then). I have still a lot to learn!

Comment: Big thx to both of you guys, you helped me a lot and both solutions lead to exactly what I wanted to achieve! The explanations helped me to understand what you did and to realize similar tasks on my own.